# If div is in middle of viewport, start css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to start an CSS animation when the div is in the middle of the viewport. My code works, but only starts when it's in the beginning of the viewport.
What calculation have I to do, to get the animation starting when it's in the middle of the viewport.

```js
    (function ($) {

        $.fn.visible = function (partial) {

            var $t = $(this),
                $w = $(window),
                viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
                viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
                _top = $t.offset().top,
                _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
                compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
                compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

            return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

        };

    })(jQuery);

    var win = $(window);

    var allMods = $(".slider-view");

    allMods.each(function (i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("already-visible");
        }
    });

    win.scroll(function (event) {

        allMods.each(function (i, el) {
            var el = $(el);
            if (el.visible(true)) {
                el.addClass("come-in");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: If I give you a vanilla JS solution that works for you?

Comment: @NikhilSingh
I would like it more if I need to only change the calculation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into Waypoints in JavaScript. I've personally used them in one of my React projects but none in any vanilla JS projects. Waypoints are very useful for triggering certain events once you've scrolled through a certain portion of an HTML element. You can also control the point at which you want the event to be triggered by altering the offset values.